# How to invoke jquery that was called on $(document).ready(), when making pjax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pjax

I am a pjax beginner and not sure if the way I am implementing it, is correct. I had an old project with a lot of jquery. To organize it a little, the method that I followed was, to assign a unique ID to the body of each page `<body id="Login">`. In my layout, I had written the code:

```
var page = $('body').attr('id');
if(page !== '' && typeof self[page] != 'undefined')
   self[page].init();
```

For page specific jquery, I had written something like this:

```
var Login = (function() {
    var funct = {};

    //any variables, only required on this page

    funct.someFunction = function(){
      //code
    }

    funct.init = function(){
        //all the functions that are to be called on page load
    }
    return funct;

})();
```

Now, on each page load, only the code required on the page is executed. However, I am now making most of the link to a pjax link. So, on login page, there is a link:

```
<a data-pjax href="/register">Register</a>
```

and the layout has the code:

```
$(document).pjax('a[data-pjax]', '#pjax-container');
```

This opens up the register page. However, since the body id was still **"Login"**, it didn't load **Register.init()**.

How do I get past this?

Answer (score 1):

I have never used pjax but according to their documentation you can add an event listener to run some code after a page change is complete

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', function(event) {
  //
})
```

You should be able to do something with `event.target`, which should hopefully be the link that was clicked, in order to figure out what the new page is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up doing something similar. I have added a data-load attribute to all the pjax links, that bear the body Id of the traget page and then load the related JS accordingly. Though, it solves my problem and the pages now work, both in pjax and non-pjax modes, but I feel that it is not the most elegant solution. I might move my question to CodeReview to get that answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: P.S.: When I say, "not the most elegant", by that I mean, my approach and my code. Nothing to do with the solution you suggested. :)